# Naming convention when same type of field is in many tables?

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have quantity in many tables. Is it convention to name the fields `quantity` in each table or `sales_quantity`, `inventory_quantity`, `purchase_quantity`?

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField()

class Invenotory(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField()

class Purchase(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quantity` field is already namespaced within each model so this is ok to do.

As a matter of fact using same names makes making abstraction layers much simpler. One such example is if you `create` for a field name for when row is created, you can create abstraction layers which use that name to generate statistics for all your models to see when they are created.